# How can I replace the website title with my logo?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm using wordpress theme build with PHP, It's a demo theme so I can't insert the logo through the control panel.

the php code:

```
<header id="masthead" class="site-header <?php echo Kirki::get_option( 'general_sticky_menu' ) == '1' ? 'sticky' : 'no-sticky'; ?>" role="banner">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12 clearfix">
                <div class="site-branding">
                    <h1 class="site-title"><a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" rel="home"><?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?></a></h1>
                    <?php
                    $description = get_bloginfo( 'description', 'display' );
                    if ( $description || is_customize_preview() ) : ?>
                        <p class="site-description"><?php echo $description ; ?></p>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                </div><!-- .site-branding -->
```

Comment: I would suggest using CSS.  https://css-tricks.com/css-image-replacement/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple. Upload your Logo and replace:

```
<?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?>
```

With your image HTML.

```
<img src="logo.gif" alt="Smiley logo" height="42" width="150">
```

Answer (score 0):

1- use Site Identity in Appearance > Customize .

2- Here’s the line of code to enable theme support for a site logo:

```
add_theme_support( 'site-logo', size );
```

example of Twenty Sixteen theme

```
add_theme_support( 'custom-logo', array(
'height'      => 240,
'width'       => 240,
'flex-height' => true, ) );
```